# Android Canvas rectangle change color

Tags: android

I have a custom view with a rectangle:

```
mCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50, paint);
```

I want to change the fill of the rectangle based on touch input.

How do I change the paint after the rectangle has been drawn?

Comment: call `invalidate()` and do the drawing inside `onDraw()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the paint like that. You need to redraw the rectangle.

Comment: mCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50, differentPaint);